# How to loop through ids with same prefix

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, loops, local-storage

I have this section of code that saves a list item on click to localStorage based on the list item's id number. On a different page I am then able to load whatever list items were saved.

```
var save1075 = $('#store-1075').get(0);
$('#store-1075').on('click', function () { 
    var storeStorageKey1075 = $(this).attr('id'); 
    localStorage.setItem('storeStorageKey1075', $(this).attr('id'));
    localStorage.setItem('storeStorageKey1075', this.innerHTML);
});

if ( localStorage.getItem('storeStorageKey1075') ) {
save1075.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('storeStorageKey1075'); 
}

var storeStorageKey1075 = $(this).attr('id');
    if ( localStorage.getItem('storeStorageKey1075') ) {
    storeStorageKey1075 = localStorage.getItem('storeStorageKey1075');

}
```

Right now I have to repeat that chunk of code for every individual id number and I'm trying to instead make the id number a variable that loops through all possible id numbers when clicked but only saves the id of that specific one. Maybe something along the lines of this:

```
var id = //some sort of loop or array of possible ids.
var save = $('#store-'+id).get(0);
$('#store-'+id).on('click', function () { 
    var storeStorageKey = $(this).attr('id'); 
    localStorage.setItem('storeStorageKey', $(this).attr('id'));
    localStorage.setItem('storeStorageKey', this.innerHTML);
});

if ( localStorage.getItem('storeStorageKey') ) {
save.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('storeStorageKey'); 
}

var storeStorageKey = $(this).attr('id');
    if ( localStorage.getItem('storeStorageKey') ) {
    storeStorageKey = localStorage.getItem('storeStorageKey');

}
```

Each of the list items has the same prefix of "store-" and the numbers are in no specific order but randomly generated each time a new store location is created.

Comment: Why are you setting the `storeStorageKey` in `localStorage` to the `id` and them immediately overwriting it with the `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is to add a class but you could also:

```
var elems = $( "[id^='store']")

elems.on( "click", function() {//Save html on click
    localStorage.setItem( this.id, this.innerHTML );
});

    //Retrieve html
elems.each( function() {
    var html = localStorage.getItem( this.id );

    if( html ) {
        $(this).html( html );
    }
});
```

Comment: Or use, <cough> the `name` attribute (so to not mix with CSS)

Comment: The id has nothing to do with styling in this case.

Comment: Esailija said "The obvious thing to do is to add a class", i was just adding or `name`. In this case we dont know if `class` are being used for styling. heck, we dont know if `id` or `name` are either!

Comment: +1. As side note, I recommend using `element[id^='prefix']`, such as `div[id^='store']` when possible, for performance benefits.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit `name`s are horrible imo, there is no short-hand selector and no built-in support for multiple names. You can have multiple classes on an element and select according to one class. `class="js-item red blue"` with `$(".js-item")` for instance

Comment: Sorry, but this answer really seems incomplete. It doesn't explain how to avoid the repetitious code.

Comment: @Esailija - yes, you are right... hence the <cough>, lol.  But you can select them all nicely `document.getElementsByName` as you know. I wasnt suggesting that `names` was better, haha. Just an alternative.

Comment: +1 This seems like the intent of the code as best I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

This loops over all keys that begin with `storeStorageKey`:

```
for (var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    if (/^storeStorageKey/.test(key)) {
        var item = localStorage.getItem(key);
        // do something with item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a prefix in the id I'd suggest adding a class to indicate that an item is storable:

```
<div class="storable" id="store-1234">...</div>
```

then you can use the class to select all the storable things in one go:

```
$('.storable').on('click', function () { 
    var storeStorageKey = $(this).attr('id'); 
    ...
});
```